# Keep only numbers outside the brackets in linux shell

Tags: shell, grep

I have a huge amount of data in the following format:

```
[ [0] = 66, [1] = 12, [2] = 16, [3] = 36, [4] = -106,
```

And I want to keep only the numbers that equals square brackets separated by spaces, so the output of the above example will be:

```
66 12 16 36 -106
```

The initial data was much more complex and I managed to reach this point but I can't handle it by myself anymore. Could you please give me some hints? I'm quite new in Linux.

Comment: Please show your initial data. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: `echo [ [0] = 66, [1] = 12, [2] = 16, [3] = 36, [4] = -106, | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep -v '[=[]' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/,/ /g'`

Comment: Probably better to use `awk`, but you might like: `sed -E 's/[^=]*=([-[:space:][:digit:]]*),/\1/g'`  (This is fragile, and will have issues if the trailing comma is missing or if the format is slightly off, but it works for your example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fragile approach that works with the sample data you've provided:

```
sed -E 's/[^=]*=([-[:space:][:digit:]]*),/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\[[^]]+]|[=,]/,""); $1=$1} 1' file
66 12 16 36 -106
```

Comment: An explanation of this awk (for the regular expression part) is given here: https://regex101.com/r/jnfQzg/1.  Finally the `$1=$1` replaces multiple spaces by a single space, and the `1` at the end produces the output.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1** : muuuuch cleaner `regex` :

```
echo '[ [0] = 66, [1] = 12, [2] = 16, [3] = 36, [4] = -106,' |
```

> ```
> mawk 'NR % 2 * NF' RS='[^0-9-]+' ORS=' '
> ```

```
66 12 16 36 -106
```

---

```
echo '[ [0] = 66, [1] = 12, [2] = 16, [3] = 36, [4] = -106,' |
```

> ```
> gawk NF RS='[^=]+(= )?' ORS=' '
> ```

```
66 12 16 36 -106
```